# Convert RGB Color to HEX Color Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am not able to get correct hex values when I try to convert the rgb color from JSON string to the HEX code. This is my code

```
lane :test_code do
  update_android_strings(
    xml_path: 'app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml',
    block: lambda { |strings|
      color_json = JSON.parse(ENV['SPLASHSCREEN_COLORS'], symbolize_names: true)
      red = (color_json[:red].to_f * 255).round
      green = (color_json[:green].to_f * 255).round
      blue = (color_json[:blue].to_f * 255).round
      color_value = "#" + (red + green + blue).to_s

      puts color_value
      # string['splashColors'] = color_value
    }
  )
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try it this way:

```
  red = color_json[:red].to_i.to_s(16)
  green = color_json[:green].to_i.to_s(16)
  blue = color_json[:blue].to_i.to_s(16)
  color_value = sprintf("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b)
```

Comment: Be careful. If `color_json[:red]` is `"15"`, the result would be `"f"` which just gets directly put into the final string. You may want to just convert these values to ints, then use something like `sprintf("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b)`.

Comment: Regarding your edit: you have to remove the `to_s(16)` conversion when using `%02x`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's get a two digit hex code for a value using `sprintf`.

E.g.

```
irb(main):003:0> color = 15
=> 15
irb(main):004:0> sprintf "%02x", color
=> "0f"
irb(main):005:0>
```

Then we can avoid repetition of code by mapping over an array of the color names created with `%w(red green blue)`. We'll map each color name to its corresponding two digit hex code, then join those together and interpolate that into a string with a leading `#`.

```rb
lane :test_code do
  update_android_strings(
    xml_path: 'app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml',
    block: lambda { |strings|
      color_json = JSON.parse(ENV['SPLASHSCREEN_COLORS'], symbolize_names: true)
      colors = %w(red green blue)
      codes = colors.map { |c| sprintf "%02x", color_json[c].to_i }
      puts "##{codes.join}"
    }
  )
end
```

Or we could simply map to the integers, and then expand that array out into the args to `sprintf`, like so:

```rb
lane :test_code do
  update_android_strings(
    xml_path: 'app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml',
    block: lambda { |strings|
      color_json = JSON.parse(ENV['SPLASHSCREEN_COLORS'], symbolize_names: true)
      colors = %w(red green blue)
      puts sprintf("#%02x%02x%02x", *colors.map { |c| color_json[c].to_i })
    }
  )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work quite nicely.

```
color_json = JSON.parse(ENV['SPLASHSCREEN_COLORS'], symbolize_names: true)
color_value = '#' + %i[red green blue].map { |c| color_json[c].to_i.to_s(16).rjust(2, '0') }.join
puts color_value
```

`String#rjust` lets you add padding to a string to make sure its length is always greater than or equal to the specified number.

```
"1".rjust(3, '-') #=> "--1"
"21".rjust(3, '-') #=> "-21"
"321".rjust(3, '-') #=> "321"
"4321".rjust(3, '-') #=> "4321"
```